# Get Experiation Date of App Certificate from within App

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I try to get the provisioning profile/certificate experiation date for iOS Apps which are deployed with Apple Developer Enterprise program. Is their some API to do this from within the App?
I want read the date and show the user a message that he might update his App, because he has only x days left, till it stops working.
I found a solution to do this from ipa file, but not from the installed App itself.

Regards,
keo9ren

Comment: Can you provide any code or pseudo code that describe when and where you want to do that.

Comment: Lets say e.g. I have a button in my App labeled 'Check  Experiation Date' which then uses a function like `getExperationDate()` which returns the date, when the applications experies and  shows this to the user. Is this helpful?

Comment: You really should deploy enterprise apps via an MDM. That way you can simply push a new provisioning profile before the current one expires.

Comment: I suppose your right, but that's not my decision. Anyway thanks for the comments.